# Where should I ask a question about a wireless printer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a new printer that I'm trying to hook up to my network, and wanted to ask for help. I looked through all the sites and none of them seemed to be right for my question. Which site should I use? Does such a site even exist?

Comment: Is this at home or at work? Also, I'm sorry to say that nobody will be able to tell you what "PC LOAD LETTER" means, so I hope that's not your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can post such a question on [Super User](http://superuser.com). But don't make your question broad, explain what specific problems you have encountered. That'd be good to also show your attempts to connect your printer to your network. In other words, don't forget to visit [the help center](https://superuser.com/help) before posting, and read especially [this](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) articles :)